# Does the flutter awesome notification have an enddate function?

Tags: flutter, awesome-notifications

```
await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
        content: NotificationContent(
          id: id,
          channelKey: "alerts",
          title: title,
          body: body,
          payload: {
            'navigate': 'DetailsPage', 
            "endDate" : endDate,
          },
        ),
        schedule:
            NotificationCalendar(hour: hour, minute: minute, repeats: true));
```

I wrote the code this way, put enddate in the payload, but it didn't really work. I want to delete the notification on a certain date and make it no longer work.

I tried putting a value in the payload, but it didn't really work.